# /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu filling up disk space, nothing seems to work

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, 20.04, disk, disk-usage

I can't use removable media, uninstall programs, or even delete files using the terminal because my disk space is full. I had plenty of space yesterday, but apparently /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu is a problem now. No commands have worked, and moving files to another hard drive doesn't affect anything.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual booting machine with Windows 10. I have a 1 TB hard drive, with 412.9 gigabytes used by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You could boot from a USB, and examine the hard drive to see what is taking so much space.  the command `sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20` run at the root of the disk will scan all the files, and display the 20 largest directories.  You can then `cd` into the one which looks unusually large...  It does take a little wile for the program to run the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a live system from a USB stick and install QDirStat on that live system (yes, that works!). Then use QDirStat to examine where all that disk space went.

If you use Btrfs, snapshots may have accumulated to fill your disk.